# View is not showing on screen

Tags: react-native

I have the code below:

```
<ImageBackground style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}} source={require('../img/bg.png')}>

  <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
  </View>

  <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
    <Text style={{fontSize:40}}>RESULTADOS</Text>
  </View>

  <View style={{flex:6, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
    <ScrollView style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'blue'}}>

      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
      //THIS NOT SHOW
      </View>

      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'green'}}>
      //THIS NOT SHOW
      </View>

    </ScrollView>
  </View>

</ImageBackground>
```

The View whit background color white and green is not showing on the screen.

Anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The`ScrollView`  component has a special prop to set style for the content. It's the `contentContainerStyle`

Instead of using

```
 <ScrollView style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
```

Just use

```
 <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
```

Click [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentcontainerstyle) to get more details.